# What is this "1;#" for when get column as string in workflow?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list ClientList which includes some companies info. Now, I create an approval workflow on a library which has a column 'Client'. At the end of workflow, I need to lookup the client column in ClientList, and then get the ApprovedLibrary column value.

[image]

**The above is the ClientList. The title is 'Sun'.**

[image]

But then if I log the lookup result, I noticed that the title value becomes **1;#Sun** . A

Anyone knows why? Where does this 1;# come from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the id of listitem "Sun". This is how SharePoint stores lookup values internally.

If you want to get rid of the preceding characters, refer

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/be71fb62-c206-4868-b2d0-5cec2623a9cd/using-lookupfields-in-workflowshow-to-get-rid-of-the-2-syntax-?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious